# Adding in-app purchase to existing published application and testing it without publishing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'm trying to add in-app purchase for my existing published app that didn't previously have billing permission. I've uploaded an updated APK with billing permission, but didn't activate it since I don't want to publish this draft. However, I can't add in-app product - it still says "the current application version does not use the BILLING permission". 
Any way to solve/work around this problem?

Comment: You upload it and activate it. Then save as draft, **not publish**. You can still save as a draft for a live app, if you upload a new version

Comment: @Blundell: I don't understand. I can activate/deactivate APKs, and I can save the whole thing, which will make all the active APKs published. I don't see a way to activate and save without publishing.

Comment: I have done this myself and trying to remember the steps, hence comment and not answer. I've got this vague memory that, if you upload it don't activate it like you said and hit save (so your unactivated apk has the permission) you should be able to add items! Are you sure you've got the billing permissions correct? I know it's possible so you are just going to have to do some trial and error

Comment: @Blundell: Permissions are correct. When I activate the new dummy APK (version 36, and the APK I need to remain published is 34) I get a message: `Error: APK version 34 supports all the same devices as other APKs with higher versions. It would not be served. Please deactivate an APK.`

Comment: why don't you try to sign your apk and test the in-app billing in that way...I guess it should work, because while app is signed with android debug key, you can't test in-app...

Comment: @Android-Developer: if it was unsigned Google Play wouldn't let me upload it.

Comment: No, it should be signed with your key, but im not sure if you must upload it to the store. Just sign an apk file with another key, not android debug, and try with the test products if you will be able to use them.

Comment: @Android-Developer: I think you misunderstood my question. I'm having problem with adding products to Google Play in the first place. That's exactly what I need to do right now.

Comment: Do you have a merchant account in google? If you don't have and your country is not supported you won't be able to add in-app products until you add a merchant account.

Comment: @Android-Developer: Yes I have it. As stated in the question, the proble I need to solve is `the current application version does not use the BILLING permission`.

Comment: hmm that's not something which I had to deal while i was implementing in-app billing to my app.My suggestion in that case is just to add in-app permission to your current app and upload it without any other changes and publish it. After that I guess you will be able to create in-app products and everything you need. Hope that helps and works for you.

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html on the bottom you have 6 steps that needs to be done in order to test in app purchase. And also verify that you done this: The application does not need to be published, but the item does need to be published

Comment: @Alex: That's not what I need, it's about testing new application that you upload from scratch, no problems there.

Comment: @Violet Giraffe There is nothing about a new application, I used those steps to add in-app purchase into my existing, published app. Of course version of application that you test should be a new one with defined permission

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Did you ever figure a way around this? I published my app a few hours ago with Billing permissions (just bit the bullet and tried disabling those features... even though there is a ton of other features in this update that are not test ready, but whatever thanks google play) and still seeing that stupid message. Did it take a few hours for it to come through?

Comment: @K2xL: it did take a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Change Android version code in Androidmanifest.xml file.

`android:versionCode="1"`

suppose if your Application version code is 1 now change to 2

Comment: If I didn't increment version code it wouldn't even let me upload the new APK.